# How can return a Comma-Separated List off the set difference of Grouped By Aggregation?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm writing a query for work and my goal is to return a comma-separated list of labels in the completed status as one colukn, and a column of a CSL of those in the incomplete status in the other column. Problem is, a label is only entered into the table when someone initiates a process under that label and not if no one else ever started the label before.

Basically, we have all of the labels that are completed, but we have some to none of the labels that were not completed.

I have implemented the "completed" column by doing a STRING_AGG pretty easily, but I am stuck on how to do the reverse. So far I have a subquery drawing from a hard-coded full table of all existing labels, I just need to figure out how to feed that subquery all of the completed labels to get the set difference so I can return the set difference as another STRING_AGG.

Below is what I have so far

```
SELECT
    p.display_name AS Product_Name,
    s.region_tag AS Region_Tag,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT IF("IMPLEMENTED" = s.status, s.language, null),  ', ') AS Implemented,
    STRING_AGG((SELECT label
      FROM (SELECT "ANDROID JAVA" AS label UNION ALL
            SELECT "CPP" AS label UNION ALL
            SELECT "CSHARP" AS label UNION ALL
            SELECT "GO" AS label UNION ALL
            SELECT "JAVA" AS label UNION ALL
            SELECT "JAVASCRIPT" AS label UNION ALL
            SELECT "JSON" AS label UNION ALL
            SELECT "KOTLIN" AS label UNION ALL
            SELECT "NODE JS" AS label UNION ALL
            SELECT "PHP" AS label UNION ALL
            SELECT "PYTHON" AS label UNION ALL
            SELECT "RUBY" AS label UNION ALL
            SELECT "XML" AS label UNION ALL
            SELECT "YAML" AS label) as all_lang), ', ') AS Unimplemented
FROM samples AS s
LEFT JOIN
  products AS p
ON
  s.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY 2,1
```

From this Sample Table...

```
Product Name | Region Tag | s.status     | Language 
---------------------------------------------------------
HP           |            | Implemented  | Go
---------------------------------------------------------
HP           |            | In Progress  | Python
---------------------------------------------------------
HP           |            | Implemented  | Javascript
---------------------------------------------------------
Asus         |            | Implemented  | PHP
```

What I want is a table like this:

```
Product Name | Region Tag | Implemented    | Not-Implemented
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
HP           |            | GO, Javascript | Python, PHP....
ASUS         |            | PHP            | Python, Go, Javascript...
```

Comment: provide sample data for your tables and expected result based on that data

Comment: Done. I put in a sample and the full result of what I'm expecting off of that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'HP' Product_Name, 'Implemented' status, 'Go' `language` UNION ALL
  SELECT 'HP', 'In Progress', 'Python' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'HP', 'Implemented', 'Javascript' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Asus', 'Implemented', 'PHP' 
)
SELECT
  Product_Name,
  MAX(IF(status = 'Implemented', list, '')) AS Implemented,
  MAX(IF(status != 'Implemented', list, '')) AS Not_Implemented
FROM (
  SELECT Product_Name, status,
    STRING_AGG(`language`) list
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY Product_Name, status
)
GROUP BY Product_Name
```

with result

```
Row Product_Name    Implemented     Not_Implemented  
1   HP              Go,Javascript   Python   
2   Asus            PHP
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the reply. Unfortunately, what I need is not all of the languages in progress, but I need the set of all languages that do not exist in the set of 'implemented' languages.

So for Asus, for example, the Not_Implemented column would be Python, Go, Javascript if the set of all languages was PHP, Python, Go, Javascript. For HP, the not_implemented column would be Python and PHP.

Comment: so, make your sample data better to present what you really want! so far the answer i gave you represent input data and expected result you presented in question!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You might note that for my expected result, "Python" exists in both "Not Implemented" columns and for "Asus" it contains all languages that are not "PHP".

It's not an easy problem to explain over text.

Comment: To further complicate matters, if there was a "Ruby" value that existed, it would go under both "Not Implemented" columns as well. Thus, my initial idea to hard-code a table in a subquery to try and find the set that does not exist in a set.

Comment: i think, i got the idea now - will be able to get back to this in an hour or two :o) so check update by then :o)

Comment: I appreciate the effort.

Comment: Hey, actually I spoke with my manager and I managed to convince him that the second column that I needed in my requirements was much less useful than the column you produced. We both agreed it would be a better idea to just move on, since who really needs the complementary set of languages? I wouldn't be all that useful to see since you already understood that information implicity from reading the first column.


Thanks so much for your help, I can definitely tweak your answer a bit to fit what I need.